# jQuery attr("href") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a wordpress theme. At the bottom of the post I inserted a custom navigation bar where I display tags and pagination links. (all wordpress elements work fine: wordpress is not the problem that brought me here)

I would like to use the javascript method .load() to refresh the post content when I click on a page number link (Basically I want to navigate through the post's pages without reloading all the stuff at each time)

To do that, I need to retrive the href attribute of the link I want to load. After reading the official APIs and searched on several forums I'm trying to achieve that through this code... but it doesn't work and I can't get why.

The HTML

```
<nav id="tag-and-navigation">
    <div class="page-numbers tags-and-navigation-elem">
        <a href="my_first_page">1</a>
        <a href="my_second_page">2</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The jQuery (debugging mode version: I just try to display in the console the href)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

this code display "undefined" on the console, while I attend "my_first_page". Any clue? Thanks

Comment: `$(this)` in your code refers to the enclosing div (which doesn't have an href).

Comment: Change JS DOM selector to `$('.tags-and-navigation-elem > a')` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your referenced element is not an `anchor` tag.

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

You could say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem a').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are selecting a div using `$('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem')`, which doesn't have `href` attribute.

You might want to say

```
console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
```

OR

If you want to click on `anchors` and get their `hrefs` use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem a').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Then it will console log all the href for all a elements inside that div. Not sure that whats he wants. But just so you know

Comment: @MikkelDamm: No, it'll show only the first. jQuery's getter/setter functions (like `attr`, `prop`, `val`, and such) are asymmetrical: When you're *setting*, they set on all elements in the set, but when you're *getting*, they get from only the first.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, your right - sorry - but I am assuming thats not what he's want when his example shows multiple a tags. Therefor I don't think that this solution "$(this).find('a').attr('href')" would help him very much.

Comment: @MikkelDamm I had just given an idea, I thought of two possibilities what he might want, and I added both in my answer, and if you'll see the accepted answer, it's the same as my second part of answer.

Comment: @MikkelDamm: Indeed, with the multiple anchors in there, your solution (which Mritunjay also added later) makes more sense to me. (And in my view should have been the accepted answer, but the OP is totally free to accept any answer they like.)

Comment: @Mritunjay I added my comment before you added your second solution - therefor my comment - but I agree with you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery selector Is selecting the div element and not the a tag. Therefor $(this) will be the div element.

Instead change your selector to this:

```
$('.page-numbers.tags-and-navigation-elem a')
```

Then it will work :)

Comment: True, but it also means that clicks outside the anchor but within the div won't work anymore.

Comment: @T.J Crowder , yes thats correct, but from what I am seing whats he tries to do, then he is trying to output the href for a single element and not all

Comment: Indeed, since the OP has more than one anchor in the div, they'd want to do this on a per-anchor basis, not a per-div basis.